# How do I concatenate Memo fields in Access using VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am migrating data from one data model to another and in doing so I need to concatenate a number of different Memo fields into one in order to prevent any data loss.

I'm not very familiar with VBA but I understand that using an Update query limits my Memo fields to 255 characters.

Can someone please provide some insight into how I should tackle this using VBA.

Example of what I'd like to achieve:

The comments for each record will be a result of concatenating 3 Memo fields:
[Comments] = [Memo1] & [Memo2] & [Memo3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load your table as a `DAO.Recordset` and update the *Comments* field in each row.

Although this is a RBAR (row by agonizing row) approach, since it's for a migration, hopefully it will be something you need do only once.  The main benefit is it won't choke with text amounts greater than 255 characters.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("YourTable", dbOpenTable)
With rs
    Do While Not .EOF
        .Edit
        !Comments.Value = !Memo1.Value & !Memo2.Value & !Memo3.Value
        .Update
        .MoveNext
    Loop
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thank you! I spent more time than I'd like to admit deliberating how to solve this. Very much appreciated.

Comment: I would like to add some clarifying text (i.e. Detection Method: _Memo1_) and spaces into my Comments field, but only if there is text in my Memo 1, 2 and 3 fields.  What is the best way to tackle this?

Comment: Nevermind!  I figured something out.  Thanks for your help. :)